# Kurento Media Server not recording because of autosigned certificate

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, kurento

I'm working with the code of an old-ish application, that is working fine in the original server but that I can't seem to get working locally on my computer. It is a web app that uses Node.js and Kurento for video streaming. I'm using the same Kurento config, and the same OS and Kurento version that's in the server. The code is also the same, it has just been copied and pasted to my local computer (although I had to change a few config params such as ips, obviously, but nothing major). Everything in the application works fine, including the video streaming, except for the recording.

The app is supposed to create a video file with the contents of the stream after it has finished. However, it does absolutely nothing. It doesn't create such recording, but it also doesn't throw any error or log any exception messages either. Here are the recorder params (for the RecorderEndpoint):

```
const recordParams = {
    mediaPipeline: pipeline,
    uri: 'https://x.x.x.x:8443/kurento/video/' + roomId,
    mediaProfile: 'WEBM',
    stopOnEndOfStream: true
};
```

The uri calls another method of my controller, which essentially post-processes the video. Here's such method:

```
router.post('/kurento/video/:roomId', function (req, res) {

    log.debug("TEST");

    ...

});
```

I can't even log the "TEST" message, which means the method is not getting called at all. I've also tried with router.put btw.

However, if I change the uri for a local file address, such as:

```
uri: file:////var/lib/kurento/test.webm
```

the app works perfectly fine, which means that the problem is with my uri rather than my recorder object itself.

I tried making petitions with postman to this uri, and found that I got an error if I didn't disable "SSL certificate verification" first, which makes sense since I'm using an autosigned certificate in my local machine. So, my question is: could this be the problem? if so, how can I work around it? I can fake a certificate (and in fact have done so and tested in postman that it threw no errors) but kurento requires an IP, not a domain name, and calling directly the ip still throws the same error as before..

Comment: I had this problem about 3 months ago. Read installation instructions carefully, You need to set keys and FQDN using valid ssl certificate ( like lets encrypt )

Comment: Thanks man, I'm gonna look into that, and report back here my results when I'm finished